# How to synchronize one product from stage to online version in hybirs?

Tags: synchronization, sap-commerce-cloud

I am in middle of workflow. I have a product model for which the the workflow is triggered. Now I need to sync this particular product from stage to online version ?

How to proceed ? Is there any method where we pass this product model , source catalog version and target catalog version ? and the output will sync this particular product ?

Thanks, Sanjay Vithani

Comment: Please tell us where exactly you stand in your workflow

Comment: I am inside public WorkflowDecisionModel perform(final WorkflowActionModel action) function. From action parameter I can get the product model. final ProductModel productModel = getAttachedProduct(action); I want this product model to sync from stage to online

Comment: Any reason to use sync mechanism? Why not update both CatalogVersions directly?

Comment: It will be a load to sync whole catalog if there are millions of product.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Impex import and export just export you model from  the stage server and import it in production by using HAC/console/Impex Import

Comment: I agree to sync only one product exporting (staging) / importing (online) catalog using impex sounds like a good option.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization is moving into Online catalog version after successfully testing Staged version. Synchronization can be done with HMC (Hybris Management Console).

1. Go to Catalog -> Catalog Management tools -> Synchronization
2. Select the website you want to synchronize e.g. Powertools, Training, Apparel
3. Go to Catalog Versions (3rd tab)
4. Right click on the staged version of your website and select create new Synchronization.
5. Select Staged version as source and Online version as Target and Save it.
6. Go back to Catalog Versions (3rd tab) and hit Synchronization
7. Select your website and click Start.

Alternative approach is to run all your impex with Online version instead of Staged but this is not advisable. Because when you are working on a project where you need to write so many impex it will be difficult to sync this way therefore above method is slandered and ethical.

Answer (score 0):

Hybris uses CronJobs to perform syncing of Catalogs. You should take a look at `CatalogVersionSyncCronJobModel` and set your one instance directly on that job. Afterwards you can throw it at the `CronJobService` (you can choose if `synchronous` or not).

We use that mechanism quite extensively, but to our surprise Hybris themself does not recommend that process (any longer). We encountered various problems on our way and you should think about implementing a content release strategy for yourself, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a change to a product, you will more than likely do it to the staged catalog. This is your intermediary to ensure information is correct before going live (especially useful if you have a workflow process in place). 
In order to synchronize this information, you will need to login to the product cockpit. Find the staged version of the catalog on the left hand menu, right click on it, and select "Sync Selected Versions". This will transfer your information into the Online catalog.

When you arrive on the product listings page and the search results page, the information contained is more than likely indexed by SOLR. In order for any changes to be reflected, you will need to re-index. To do this:
HMC   >   System > Facet Search > Indexer Operation Wizard
A pop-up window will appear. Select the Indexer operation as update and the Solr configuration to the index associated with your website.